# User not Defined in Models.py Function

Tags: python, django

How do I turn this into a function that can be called from a template?

```
>>> var1 = coremodels.Recommendation.objects.get(title="test5")
>>> user = User.objects.get(username='admin') // should get self.request.user
>>> var1.vote.exists(user)
```

#### Current Attempt:

I currently have it in models.py but getting error `global name 'user' not defined`:

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    def check_user_voted(self):
        user_voted = self.votes.exists(user)
        return user_voted
```

This is the html request:

```
{% if recommendation.check_user_voted %}
    <p>User Voted</p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Can you post your full model?

Comment: @Gocht sure: http://pastebin.com/QqJqZv8E Though i think this should be in views.py (just unsure how to create the function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your function doesn't need parameters, it can be called from templates:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#variables

In your `check_user_voted` function, `user` is not defined. It should be:

```
def check_user_voted(self):
    user_voted = self.votes.exists(self.user)
    return user_voted
```

Answer (score 0):

To call a function from template, you need to use the decorator `@property`

```
class Recommendation(models.Model):
    ...

    @property
    def check_user_voted(self):
        ....
        return something
```

Then you call it from a Recommendation object: `reco_object.check_user_voted`

Finally, to reference the user associated to the current `recommendation` object, you need to use `self.user` which will return the `User` object once the `recommendation` object has one associated.

```
def check_user_voted(self):
    user_voted = self.votes.exists(self.user)
    return user_voted
```

Comment: It doesn't have to be a property to call it from a template. It will just be called without parameters: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/templates/#variables

Comment: In fact, using the `@property` tag suggests it is a very 'lightweight' function, and because this is a database call, isn't that lightweight. This is not a rule, just a convention.

Comment: That example is about sending data from views, I talk about call a function in template.

Comment: "If a variable resolves to a callable, the template system will call it with no arguments and use its result instead of the callable."